# Updating variable in Foreach

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to update a variable with the following way:

```
@{ double totalPrice = 0;}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

       @{totalPrice += item.Price; }
}
```

I'm not sure if it is possible.. If so, what is the right syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is possible but try to modify your code

```
@{ double totalPrice = 0;}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

   totalPrice += item.Price;
}
@totalPrice;
```